# display final content of DE value with personalization strings to another DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

i have 2 DEs in use: 'journey_sends' for use as entry in a journey and 'content_sms' where i keep content for SMS sending

for 'content_sms', i have a 'content' column with values that have personalization strings. e.g:

*dear customer, your order %%order_number%% is being processed*

%%order_number%% will get its value in 'journey_sends' DE.

now what we would like to do is to extract the content values but is **processed** to another DE -- so instead of

*dear customer, your order %%order_number%% is being processed*

, it would show

*dear customer, your order 123456 is being processed*

in the DE. how can i do this? is this possible without coding?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: hi @zuzannamj! we are previously using mobile connect, but now migrating to an external sms sender, so at this point we would like to extract the final content since data is coming in through the journey_sends of who are eligible for SMS sending.